# UITextField keyboard can't type anything

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uitextfield, uiactionsheet

load a xib file as a UIView, and I got a UITextField form a Xib file(it just a view that contains textfield and button).
But when the app launched and that textfield comes up. i cannot type any alphabet on this UITextField.
But paste a text to that UITextField was OK. Why?
Here is my adding code

```
-(IBAction)showSheet{    
    UIView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginViewComp" owner:self options:NULL] lastObject];    
     [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 400)];

    UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)[myView viewWithTag:101];
    UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[myView viewWithTag:102];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[myView viewWithTag:103];    

    [field setEnabled:YES];

    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(testBtn1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    DTActionSheet *sheet = [[DTActionSheet alloc] initWithContentView:myView sheetTitle:@"Demo"];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
    [sheet setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)testBtn1{
    NSLog(@"btn1 touch up inside");     
}
@end
```

DTActionSheet.m

```
@interface DTActionSheet()
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView* contentView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIToolbar* toolBar;
@end

@implementation DTActionSheet
@synthesize contentView=_contentView;
@synthesize toolBar=_toolBar;

-(id)initWithContentView:(UIView*)contentView sheetTitle:(NSString*)title;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        _contentView = contentView;
        int btnnum = (contentView.frame.size.height-5)/50; // (height+44-20-25)/50
        for(int i=0; i<btnnum; i++)
        {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:@" "];
        }
        _toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        _toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

        UIBarButtonItem *titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                       target:nil 
                                                                       action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:@selector(done)];

        UIBarButtonItem *leftButton  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                       target:self 
                                                                       action:@selector(cancel)];

        UIBarButtonItem *fixedButton  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                                      target:nil 
                                                                                      action:nil];

        [_toolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftButton,fixedButton,titleButton,fixedButton,rightButton,nil]];

        [self addSubview:_toolBar];
        [self addSubview:_contentView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)done
{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
-(void)cancel
{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
@end
```

[image: Xib component]

[image: Cannot input any alphabet and number into these 2 text fields]

Hey, guys, have any idea?

Comment: Can you make sure your textfield's delegate working or not?

Comment: did u solve the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

try using UIKeyInput Protocol Reference for input --
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

make sure to use its delegate..